# Nodejs memory cache thread safety

Tags: node.js, thread-safety

I have a Node service. The node service has a memory cache, it's an in-memory key-value store. The node service also running a periodic task runs every day which is rebuild cache (CPU intensive and cost a lot of time).  When rebuild cache task is running, Will it block other /get request? Is there any race condition here?

```
/get: get the cache data by key

setInterval(()=>{ rebuildCache() ; }, 3600)

async rebuildCache(filepath: string, key: string): Promise<void> {
  const obj = constructFromFile(filepath) 
  //load json from filepath. do some cpu intensitive work. (build schema, reference, etc)

  cache[key] = obj
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it block other /get request?

It depends upon what `rebuildCache()` does and how it works.  If it's a synchronous operation (entirely CPU), then that will block the event loop and will block all request processing.

> Is there any race condition here?

It depends upon how the code that uses the cache is written and what `rebuildCache()` does.  If any operations that uses the cache are asynchronous and they depend upon cache consistency from before it runs an asynchronous operation to after it finishes an asynchronous operation, then a `rebuildCache()` can occur in that window of time and you could indeed have a race condition.

---

The devil is in the details of your actual implementation for both code using the cache and the function that rebuilds the cache so we can only offer hypothetical answers without seeing the actual code.

---

FYI, this code in your question:

```
setInterval(rebuildCache())
```

only calls `rebuildCache()` once.  To actually call it on any interval, you would need something like this:

```
setInterval(rebuildCache, t);
```

Note, you pass a function reference (without the parens) and you pass a time for the timer interval.

Comment: Hi, @jfriend00. I have updated the question. Could you please take a look and update your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @王若璇 - You aren't showing any relevant code.  We would need to see ALL the code in `rebuildCache()` and all the code in the functions you call to know what it does and what influence it has on the event loop.  If it's all synchronous, the single threaded nature of the main JS thread will cause it to block the event loop and prevent other requests from being processed while it's being run.  If it's asynchronous (meaning it calls asynchronous functions), then other events/requests can be processed while those asynchronous calls are running.

Comment: @王若璇 - Remember, unless you explicitly use Worker threads (new feature in recent versions of node.js), JS is single threaded.  That means it can only run once piece of Javascript at a time.  If you're doing some long running synchronous Javascript calculations, then that's ALL it can do in the main thread.  It can't process timers, incoming network requests, etc...  You could move your long running stuff to a [Worker Thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) or a child process and then it would not block other requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot, all code in rebuildCache is related to business logic. The main task in rebuildCache is to sync read local file from disk and then build some JSON schema in memory.

Comment: @王若璇 - If you're using `fs.readFileSync()` or any synchronous file I/O, that's completely blocking.  Synchronous file I/O should never be used in a server except during startup initialization because it can wreck server scalability and will completely block the event loop.  Use asynchronous file I/O instead.  It is non-blocking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205057/discussion-between--and-jfriend00).